# JavaScript some-method doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, search

I have a function which should find the first element of an array where the index and its value are equal. I need to get the `index = 1`, but I get `-1`.

```js
function indexEqualsValue(a) {
  var currentElement = -1;
  a.some(function(element, index) {
    if (element === index) {
      return element
    }
  })
  return currentElement
}
console.log(indexEqualsValue([-5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 15]))
```

Comment: `Array#some` returns true or false, and you aren’t changing `currentElement`. Use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (or equivalent `findIndex`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never reassigning `currentElement` to the found element, so it always remains `-1`. It would probably be more appropriate to use `find` or `findIndex`, which returns the found element (or found index) - `some` returns a *boolean*, but you're not using the result of your `.some` call. Try this instead:

```js
function indexEqualsValue(a) {
  return a.findIndex((element, index) => element === index)
}
console.log(indexEqualsValue([-5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 15]))
console.log(indexEqualsValue([-5, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 15]))
console.log(indexEqualsValue([-5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 15]))
```